# Call to undefined method Google_Service_Gmail_Message::toSimpleObject()

Tags: php, codeigniter, gmail-api

I'm trying to develop a web application that send email throught Gmail API.
But I'm getting this error :

> Call to undefined method Google_Service_Gmail_Message::toSimpleObject()

Here is my code :

```
// LOAD GOOGLE LIBRARY
        $this->CI->load->library('master_google');
        $this->CI->load->library('master_phpmailer');
        $client = $this->CI->master_google->getClient($data);

        $mail = $this->CI->master_phpmailer;
        $mail->setFrom($data->sender_email, $data->sender_name);
        $mail->addReplyTo($data->response_email, $data->response_name);
        $mail->addAddress($data->email);
        $mail->Subject = $data->subject;
        $mail->msgHTML(htmlspecialchars_decode($data->body));
        $mail->preSend();
        $mime = $mail->getSentMIMEMessage();
        $encoded_message = base64url_encode($mime);

        // Gmail Message Body
        **$message = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();**
        $message->setRaw($encoded_message);

        // Send the Email
        $service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
        $email = $service->users_messages->send('me',$message);

        if($email->getId()){
            return array('stat' => true, 'msg' => '');
        } else {
            return array('stat' => false, 'msg' => '');
        }
```

The error is generated on this line :

**$message = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();**

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found what was the problem lol, I had a model with the same name : Google_model, I rename that to Mygoogle_model and it works :D

Answer (score -1):

I think the method `toSimpleObject()` does not exist in your `gmail-api` class.

Comment: It exists in Google_Model.php, and it should be included automatically cause it's part of Google api.